# Remove carriage return from form before writing to csv

Tags: php, csv

I have a php form that sends the results to an email and also writes to a csv file on the server that I download to use in openoffice calc.

The mailing works fine, and so does the writing except one aspect:
when people use the "enter" key (carriage return, right?) the new line is seen as another cell in openoffice calc, or if I open the file using notepad++ I see the lines of the same field on different lines.

How can I clean it up so that the content of the text area displays in its single cell?

I had the problem when people used commas in the fields, so I change commas with pipes, and that seems to have fixed that part.

Here is the code to write into the csv file I am using, in case you need some more of the code, please let me know.

```
$fp = fopen('/path-to-file/data.csv', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $name . '|' . $lastname . '|' . $address . '|' . $city . '|' . $country . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $messageone . '|' . $messagetwo . '|' . $comment . '|' . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);
```

*UPDATE ONE*

@Marco
Thank you for the code, I thought it was not related, but in the full code I do have the trim function, and it doesn't seem to do it, following is a more complete code of the processing file, file ends with the code to send the email messages to user, and admin - I removed many fields, but they are basically the same as the ones posted, as you can guess.

```
    $required = array('name','lastname','address','city'); // more fields here
    $all_okay = TRUE;
    $clean_post = array();
    $error = '';
    foreach($required as $key) {
        if (empty($_POST[$key])){
            $error .= "<br/>$key is a required field\n";
            $all_okay = FALSE;
        }else{
            $clean_post[$key] = $_POST[$key];
            $_SESSION[$key] = $_POST[$key];
        }
    }

    //Name
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z' -]{2,}/", trim($_POST['name']))){
        $error .= "<br /><strong>Name does not pass validation</strong>\n";
    //Lastname
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z' -]{2,}/", trim($_POST['lastname']))){
        $error .= "<br /><strong>Lastname does not pass validation</strong>\n";
    //Address
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9' -]{2,}/", trim($_POST['address']))){
        $error .= "<br /><strong>Address does not pass validation</strong>\n";

    //Continue if no error
    }elseif(empty($error)){ 

        // PREPARE THE DATA 
        $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
        $lastname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['lastname']));
        $address = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['address']));
        $city = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['city']));

// write to csv file
$fp = fopen('/path-to-file/data.csv', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $name . '|' . $lastname . '|' . $address . '|' . $city . '|' . $country . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $messageone . '|' . $messagetwo . '|' . $comment . '|' . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fp);

        // PREPARE EMAIL BODY TEXT
        $body = '';
        $Admin_body = '';
```

*UPDATE TWO*

@Marco
Thank you, the debugger displays the same way, with the "error".
I might have found the culprit, though I don't know how to solve it, but you might.
The problem is there are not text delimiter, besides the field delimiter.

I tried adding this, but while email goes thru the file is not written on.

```
fwrite($fp, '"' . $name . '"|"' . $lastname . '"|"' . $address . '"|"' . $city . '"|"' . $country . '"|"'
```

I cut the code, but did it to the last field (comment).
And I also didn't put all the trimmed fields, but they are all trimmed.

The idea of the text delimiter is from here:
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=76545&p=348709#p348709

*UPDATE THREE*

**OK, this is the solution for others if encounter same problem**
The last snip was on the right track, but I had an error in it, pipe and quote mark at the end, and I added EOL.

```
fwrite($fp, '"' . $name . '|' . $lastname . '|' . $address . '|' . $city . '|' . $country . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $messageone . '|' . $messagetwo . '|' . $comment . '"' . PHP_EOL);
```

Thank you Marco, your help, and patience greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you are actually explicitly writing the EOL though (CR + LF on windows).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatelly I am not a coder, and I can't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of newlines, extra spaces, etc. use the `trim()` function.

It can be useful to remove commas, dots and other stuff at the end of the lines, too.

See https://php.net/trim

== Here is the code ==

```
$name = trim($name);
$lastname = trim($lastname);
$address = trim($address);
$city = trim($city);
$country = trim($country);
$email = trim($email);
$messageone = trim($messageone);
$messagetwo = trim($messagetwo);
$comment = trim($comment);

$fp = fopen('/path-to-file/data.csv', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $name . '|' . $lastname . '|' . $address . '|' . $city . '|' . $country . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $messageone . '|' . $messagetwo . '|' . $comment);
fclose($fp);
```

Many users, not seeing extra spaces, think they don't exist… so we programmers have to think for them :-)

== Update ==

For a better debugging you can add these lines to your code:

```
// write to csv file
$fp = fopen('/path-to-file/data.csv', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $name . '|' . $lastname . '|' . $address . '|' . $city . '|' . $country . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $messageone . '|' . $messagetwo . '|' . $comment);
fclose($fp);
// your code ends here 
echo "<pre>";
echo "[" . $name . '|' . $lastname . '|' . $address . '|' . $city . '|' . $country . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $messageone . '|' . $messagetwo . '|' . $comment . "]";
echo "</pre";
die ("Debugging - the script stops here");
```

The script will show you the same string written on file and will "die" (stop).

If you see a carriage return before the last `]` then it is at the end of `$comment`: I noticed in your code just some of the variables are trimmed.

Comment: Thank you, problem is I don't know how to use the function, actually I am not a coder, and built the form searching, and asking on forums. Will you please tell me how? OT (è italiano?)

Comment: Basically all those `trim()` functions remove from the beginning and the end of every variable these characters: " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space — "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab — "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed) — "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return —  "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte — "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab. In this way you are sure to have just "clean" text, without broken lines.

Comment: Thanks. Shall I add your code as well before the csv write lines, since there is a difference with the trim lines I already have in the code >>> $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));   vs   $name = trim($name);

Comment: Your code is better than mine! It get rid of added slashes before the quote in names like O'Hara, too. I guess your broken lines came from the `PHP_EOL` (End-Of-Line). Since we're here, I suggest a cleanup of the data typed by the users, using a `filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` instead of a plain `$_POST['name']`. Just in case someone will try to make nasty things on your server.

Comment: Thank you. I removed EOL, but still not working, even by viewing it in notepad++ new lines are created at the carriage return.

Comment: A `var_dump($comment)` will show you the size and the content of the string, so you can visually check if the number of letters is matching with the size: if there is a difference you get the bad guy.

Comment: Thank you, see updated OP, sorry I can't upvote since I am new here.

Comment: No problems, I'm here just to ask questions, even if digging enough I can find answers for almost any one :-)